# Either BOF or EOF is True. Include EOF in Do Until

Tags: excel, eof, vba

I'm getting an error at rs.Movenext in my For Each. I've tried using a Do Until but not sure where to place it. Can someone advise where to place it? Not sure if using EOF in my Do Until will overcome the error though.

Thanks

```
    Sub FindCardOrdersv2()

    ' Initialize variables.
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim provStr As String
    Dim intMaxCol As Integer
    Dim intMaxRow As Integer
    Dim rsFilter As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rng As Variant
    Dim payid(1 To 10) As String
    Dim tw As ThisWorkbook
    Dim errmsg As String

    Workbooks("cleanse.xlsm").Activate
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

    ' Create new instances
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset


    ' sql query
    sql = "SELECT TOP 100 t.tri_transactionidcode," _
          & "SUBSTRING(t.tri_reference, 1, 9) AS merchantref," _
          & "t.tri_additionalreferencenumber, t.CreatedOn, t.tri_amount, ISNULL(t.tri_paymenttransactiontypeidName, 'Online')" _
          & " FROM dbo.tri_onlinepayment t INNER JOIN dbo.tri_transaction tr ON tr.tri_onlinepaymentid = t.tri_onlinepaymentId" _
          & " WHERE t.tri_transactionresult = 9 AND t.tri_transactionidcode IN (1013302661,1013327345, 1013172653)"



    ' Specify the OLE DB provider.
    cn.Provider = "sqloledb"

    ' Specify connection string on Open method.
    cn.Open "Data Source=IFL-SQL11;Database=IFL_MSCRM;Trusted_Connection=yes;Integrated Security=SSPI"



    ' Assign active connection to recordset
    Set rs.ActiveConnection = cn
    'intMaxCol = rs.Fields.Count

    ' Define cursors and open sql
    With rs
        .CursorLocation = adUseServer
        .CursorType = adOpenStatic
        .LockType = adLockReadOnly
        .Open sql
    End With


    For i = 1 To rs.RecordCount
       If Not (rs.BOF And rs.EOF) Then
            payid(i) = rs.Fields.Item(0)
            Debug.Print rs(0)
            Debug.Print rs(1)
            Debug.Print rs(3)
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Next i

    errmsg = "No matches found"

    For Each rsFilter In Range("A1:A10").Cells
        For i = 1 To rsFilter.Cells.Count
          'Do Until rs.EOF
            If rsFilter.Value = payid(i) Then
                   Debug.Print rsFilter.Value
                   Debug.Print rsFilter.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Else: Debug.Print errmsg & " " & rsFilter.Value

            End If
              'Loop
                    rs.MoveNext
            'Loop
        Next i
    Exit For
```

**Update**

Following your suggestion Fil, I'm getting an error at bold. Do I not need to use i as a counter? Sorry I'm a little confused because its the second For Each that I can't get to work properly. The first For works fine as far as I know. Thanks

```
'For i = 1 To rs.RecordCount
    'If Not (rs.BOF And rs.EOF) Then
    While Not rs.EOF
         **payid(i) = rs.Fields.Item(0)**
         Debug.Print rs(0)
         Debug.Print rs(1)
         Debug.Print rs(3)
     End If
     rs.MoveNext
   End While
'Next i


    **For Each rsFilter In Range("A1:A10").Cells
        For i = 1 To rsFilter.Cells.Count
          'Do Until rs.EOF
            If rsFilter.Value = payid(i) Then
                   Debug.Print rsFilter.Value
                   Debug.Print rsFilter.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Else: Debug.Print errmsg & " " & rsFilter.Value

            End If
              'Loop
                    rs.MoveNext
            'Loop
        Next i
    Exit For
    Next**
```

**Update 2**

I've fixed the BOF and EOF error I had at first by doing a a while not rs.eof before rs.movenext. But when my If is true (barclays.value = payid(i) I get another BOF/EOF is true error when I try to enter the rs.fields.item(0) back to my range. Any suggestions? Thanks

```
For Each barclays In Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Cells 
    For i = 1 To rs.RecordCount 
        If barclays.Value = payid(i) Then 
           barclays.Offset(0, 1) = rs.Fields.Item(0)
            Debug.Print barclays.Value 
            Debug.Print barclays.Offset(0, 1).Value 
        Else: 
            barclays.Offset(0, 1) = "No payment found for " & barclays.Value 
            Debug.Print "No payment found for " & barclays.Value & " for " & payid(i) 
        End If 
        While Not rs.EOF 
            rs.MoveNext 
        Wend 
    Next i 
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change:

```
    'For i = 1 To rs.RecordCount
       'If Not (rs.BOF And rs.EOF) Then
       While Not rs.Eof
            payid(i) = rs.Fields.Item(0)
            Debug.Print rs(0)
            Debug.Print rs(1)
            Debug.Print rs(3)
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
      End While
    'Next i
```

The second for doesn't nothing on the recordset so you have to remove "rs.Movenext" instruction. The "Exit For" outside a For is meaningless, so you have to remove that instruction too.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've managed to get it to work but when I try enter rs.fields.items(0) when it equals a value in my range, I'm getting another BOF and EOF is true error. The error occurs in the last For Each loop. I've updated the original post. Thanks

Comment: Oh sorry. I didn't notice. In first 'while' you need also "i+=1" as first instruction. In the second 'for' (update) you have to remove "rs.MoveNext". In the third code (update2) the while does nothing and you can remove it. I'd assign "rs.RecordCount" to a variable.